# Is the exponential map of GL(n,C) holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras, several-complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Let $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ be the complex general linear (Lie) group consisting of all invertible complex $n\times n$ matrices, and $gl(n,\mathbb{C})\cong C^{n^2}$ be its Lie algebra. The [exponential map of matrix groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) are defined by the usual infinite series. I think since all entries are infinite series this map is holomorphic between these two complex manifold. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it is correct.